# How to change background colour of an image in GIMP after increasing canvas size

Tags: gimp, background, canvas

I have expanded an image's canvas in GIMP and I'd like to change the background colour of the new area created by my increase of the canvas size. 
[image]

I've tried selecting this area but no matter what I do I cannot seem to select this area, only stuff in the area of the original canvas.

I know exporting the image as PNG, closing it and then opening the image again in GIMP will allow me to colour this area, but is there a way I can without closing the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You:

- add a new layer (`Layer>New layer`)
- fill wit with the required color: in the layer creation dialog, some of the choices are the current Foreground or background color, or white. And in any case you can bucket-fill it later with any color.
- move it below your current image, either by dragging it in the Layers list, or by using the `Layer>Stack` entries (in particular, `Lower` or `Layer to bottom`
- If necessary you can merge the layers `Image>Merge visible layers`

Now, an explanation of your problem: you can only paint within layer boundaries (the fixed dashed lines), but when you enlarge the canvas (`Image>Canvas size`), the layers remain the same and aren't enlarged by default, so you cannot paint in the added emptiness. You can change this while resizing the canvas using the `Resize` selector in the dialog, where two options are `All layers` (usually a bad idea) and `Image-sized layers` (a good idea). You can also change this at any later time using `Layer>Layer to image size` to extend the layer with transparency that you can paint on. But in any case, the method at the beginning of this answer is still the quickest/safest to fill the emptiness with color.